# Batch-file to remove part of a number before passing it to an application

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I've been racking my brain trying to get my softphone to dial numbers on web pages. I've gotten the browser to pass the number through to the softphone, but it adds tell:+ to the number and won't call out.

As a matter of last resort, I want to create a batch file to remove the tel:+ from the number. I have never written one before, but I imagine that it would be relatively simple.

The batch file just needs to open the tel: urls and remove tell:+ from the number before passing it on to the softphone.

I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Arthur, do you know if you can send a number to your softphone via the command line? If not, how do you manually send a number to it? Copy and paste? I have some ideas that could work. :)

Comment: Is this for Windows, *nix, OSX, or just on the Internet? Or is it just for mobile devices? If so, what ones?

Comment: @Luke I assumed Windows, since Arthur is asking for a Batch script. But it wasn't explicitly clarified. They haven't been here since March, though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a batch file that uses the URL as the command line argument:

```
launch.bat tell:+800-555-1212
```

then you could do something like this for your launch.bat:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set URL=%1
if not defined URL goto ERR
goto RUN

:ERR
@echo.
@echo Please give tell:+ URL on command line
@echo.
goto END

:RUN
set GOOD=%URL:~6%
@echo calling: %GOOD%
softphone.exe %GOOD%
goto END

:END
endlocal
```

When you run it, it will execute:

```
softphone.exe 800-555-1212
```

You will nee to replace "softphone.exe" accordingly.